# Javascript counter variable not incrementing only appending digits

Tags: javascript, append, counter, increment

```
  var counter = 0;

  var userAdd = prompt("How many would you like to add?");

  counter += userAdd;

  console.log(counter);
```

New to javascript.

I am trying to get the counter to increment up by the amount that the userAdd variable specifies.

When I run this code all I get from the console.log() is, for example:

If userAdd is '1' each time:

01 
011 
0111 
...etc.

instead of:

1
2
3

Whats the problem here?

Comment: `str` `+` `num` `=` `str` and `num` `+` `str` `=` `str`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to type your result as an int rather than a string.

```
var userAdd = parseInt(prompt("How many would you like to add?"));
```

This forces the numeric adding instead of the string appending.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that have an answer elsewhere. There is no need to duplicate content on the same site. I've found a duplicate question that has a better answer than yours.