# JavaScript: force 0 to be a Number so it can increment properly

Tags: javascript, numbers, increment

for some weird reason, it doesn't work worth a tinker's damn.  it **appends** when i need it to **increment**.  yes, i've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719319/cannot-use-when-try-to-add-number), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061920/javascript-counter-variable-not-incrementing-only-appending-digits) aaaand [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_oper_plusequal) (which doesn't work), but they don't really help (at all) with such a simple case.  :poop:  what **i** am trying to do, is this:

```
  var status = 0;
  console.log('status: '+status);
  status += 1;
  console.log('status: '+status);
  status += 2;
  console.log('status: '+status);
  status += 3;
  console.log('status: '+status);
  ...
```

but all it outputs is `0,01,012,0123` instead of `0,1,3,6`.  yes, it's simple, but that's what i need for this particular implementation and the stuff that connects to it. also, the steps matter; otherwise, i'd just `status++` and i obviously don't want twenty-six lines of that either. DRY, right?

i've tried to do this, `var status = Number(0);` and `var status = parseInt(0)` for fun (no way it would work, but try anyway) and even tried `status = status + 1'` (pointless variant, but cover the bases...) and none work.  what am i missing?  i understand [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462663/implied-string-comparison-0-but-1-1), yet don't know how to make `0 == Number(0)`, as it were.  i thought the increment existed to prevent kind of fumbuckery... its stupid math, for heaven's sake...

so.  how do i force the zero to be a **Number** so the increment can work as needed and output a**number** at each step along the way?

Comment: The code you posted will not do what you say it does. *edit* oh.

Comment: Seems like `status` is a window variable, you should consider changing name.

Comment: The problem is that you're running the code in the global scope, and `status` is some `window` property that really wants to be a string. Change the variable name to "timothy" or "riceNoodle" and it works fine.

Comment: works as expected to me!

status: 0
status: 1
status: 3
status: 6

Comment: @fedeghe probably depends on the environment; it'd almost certainly work in Node for example.

Comment: @Pointy exactly

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status

Comment: e.g. in chrome status is just "" ...so Kind user an Pointy got the clue

Comment: @Pointy hot damn.  that's it.  brilliant.  never thought to check if status was reserved by the DOM.  thanks!  :)  [duplicate, my ass Bergi...]

Comment: i appreciate you guys answering this question in the comments.  i obviously didn't know to even check that my variable name was the issue.  StackOverflow is so quick to slap 'DUPLICATE QUESTION' on things, expecting us to magically know where we went wrong, it makes finding answers difficult.  so thanks to everyone on this one.

Answer (score -1):

would be doing `status = +status + 1` be to much? Or the hack `+status++`?

Comment: That might kind-of work but it'd be better to just avoid stomping on whatever global symbol that is.

Comment: yeah you're completely right